# How to use/access inner friend function of class in c++?

Tags: c++, friend

We can declare and define a friend function inside a class, like below

```
class C
{
    friend void F() {cout<<"inner friend func"<<endl;}
};
```

how to access/use this inner friend func?

```
C::F() //error: 'F' is not a member of 'C'
C().F()//error: 'class C' has no member named 'F'
```

Answer (score 3):

The [friend decalration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend#Notes) declares `F()` as non-member function, then both `C::F()` and `C().F()` won't work. And you have to add a declaration in namespace scope for calling it because it's not visible for name lookup (except [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), but `F()` takes no parameters then ADL doesn't work for it).

> A name first declared in a friend declaration within a class or class template X becomes a member of the innermost enclosing namespace of X, but is not visible for lookup (except argument-dependent lookup that considers X) unless a matching declaration at the namespace scope is provided

and

> Names introduced by [friend](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) declarations within a non-local class X become members of the innermost enclosing namespace of X, but they do not become visible to ordinary [name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) (neither [unqualified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup) nor [qualified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup)) unless a matching declaration is provided at namespace scope, either before or after the class definition. Such name may be found through [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) which considers both namespaces and classes.

E.g.

```
void F();
class C
{
    friend void F() {cout<<"inner friend func"<<endl;}
};
```

Then call it like

```
F();
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/v5GaaDRYzNRWFryL)

Answer (score 1):

Declaring the function as a friend does not make it part of the class. You need to declare it outside:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class C
{
    friend void F() {cout<<"inner friend func"<<endl;}
};

void F();

int main() {
    F();
}
```

Or better, put also the definition outside of the class.